# Can't update windows8 project by using Cordova CLI

Tags: cordova, windows, cordova-cli

I create my windows 8 project by using cordova CLI.

```
cordova platform add windows8
cordova build windows8
```

However, when I tried to update the project by following the steps on [PhoneGap Documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_win8_upgrading.md.html#Upgrading%20Windows%208). I got an error indicating that "The path provided is not a path to a cordova windows phone project".

```
C:\Developer\CordovaLibraryProject>cordova platform update windows8
Error: Update script failed: Error: Command failed: The path provided is not a path to a cordova windows phone project.
Please provide the path to the root folder of your cordova windows phone project.
The path provided is not a path to a cordova windows phone project.
Please provide the path to the root folder of your cordova windows phone project.

    at C:\Users\stan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\src\platform.js:140:38
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:641:7)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
```

Is that a bug in Cordova? If not, how can I update my windows8 project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hit the same issue in 3.4.1

It looks like the update command does not support windows8. The  cordova-cli [readme](https://github.com/apache/cordova-cli/) suggests this by not listing update command under the Windows 8 section.

More concrete evidence is that the windows8 update.js command explicitly looks for a "windows phone" project and then throws the error you are seeing. I use quotes because it does this by checking for a .csproj file in the windows8 directory.

I tried rigging it to work by placing a dummy.csproj file in my platforms\windows8 folder . This got me further but still failed.

<strike>The version you are upgrading from may have some bearing on the this so maybe worth a try.</strike>

update.js has not been  [updated](https://github.com/apache/cordova-windows/tree/master/windows8/bin) (no pun intended) for a year. I'd call it a bug

I've submitted this to their bug tracker: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6748